# Where does unity store app shortcuts and how to get rid of nonfunctional/duplicate shortcuts?

Tags: unity, icons, unity-dash

I have lots of duplicate icons (with different sizes), or even icons without title in my dash. I want to get rid of those, but don't know how. I have observed, that when logging in as a different user, everything is alright.

Where does unity store all those app icons?

It has to be somewhere below my home folder, since everythings alright for other accounts. But alas, I haven't found it.

Already tried running `unity --reset`, just be informed that it's deprecated and doesn't work any more.

I am know on 12.10, but had the same problem in 12.04.

EDIT: I made a screenshot to make my problem clear:
[image]

Comment: Did you try rightclick -> remove from starter?

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is not the programs in the starter, but when I open the dash.

Comment: This screenshot is indeed very helpful :D I was misled. Hopefully someone can help you with this issue.

Comment: Solved! See my comment to tachyons answer.

Comment: Great! So if you found the answer yourself, you can post it and accept it. It's OK to [answer your own questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Icons are stored in /usr/share/applications remove duplicate icons(if any) from there.

If it won't work try

```
 sudo apt-get remove menu-xdg
```

**or**

remove the folder `~/.local/share/applications/menu-xdg`

Comment: That was nearly correct, and pointed me to the correct solution. The duplicates were stored under ~/.local/share/applications/menu-xdg. I removed that folder and now everything works as expected. If you update your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer and add that steps to answer :)